# zywall usg 100 log website visits

Tags: monitoring, router, zywall

Can I log all browsing history with a zyxel zywall usg 100 router (with no payed licenses).
I would like to see a complete list of websites visited; a bit like the "traffic statistics" page (interface "lan1", sort by "Web site hits"), but a complete history with timestamps instead of the top 20 max hits.

- I have usb-storage added to the router
- activated usb-storage in log-settings
- enabeled logging of "forward web sites" (but i don't get any results in that type of log)

Answer (score 0):

Do this by using a custom content filter:
Create a content filter profile with a trust all rule: *.*

url's will start showing up in the logs

Comment: you should be a little detailed, as I think I did what you said but nothing shows up in the logs.